# Where to add 'track by $index' when using Filter and Pagination in the same ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-track-by

I have my ng-repeat and filter  ,then I added bootstrap-ui pagination and everything working fine

To add fields Edit, I needed to use 'track by $index' but I cant find the correct way to add it to my ng-repeat,
This is my HTML view :

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="target in targets | filter:search | startFrom:(currentPage - 1) * pageSize  | limitTo: pageSize "> 
  <td><input type="text" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="updateTarget(targets[$index])" ng-model="targets[$index].YEAR"></td>
  <td><input type="text" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="updateTarget(targets[$index])" ng-model="targets[$index].MONTH"></td>
  <td><input type="text" ng-model-options="{ updateOn: 'blur' }" ng-change="updateTarget(targets[$index])" ng-model="targets[$index].TV"></td>
</tr>
```

[Here is my table screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dECrM.jpg)

My PageSize Limit is set to 5, so my index restart from 1 to 5 in every page cause I didn't added track by $index in my ng-repeat 
So if I edit row number 2, it will edit every row number 2 in every page,

Any idea for how to add 'track by $index' when using Filter and Pagination in the same ng-repeat

Answer (score 0):

According to the Angular documentation [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat):

Note: track by must always be the last expression:

```
<div ng-repeat="model in collection | orderBy: 'id' as filtered_result track by model.id">
    {{model.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `model in collection track by $index | orderBy: 'id'` works too...

Comment: I tested my ng-repeat without pagination like this :                                        <tr data-ng-repeat="target in targets | filter:search  track by $index ">     and I get my index working,   the problem is when I add "| startFrom:(currentPage - 1) * pageSize  | limitTo: pageSize  track by $index"  I cant get my table any more,          To resume Filter + Track by $index works,   Filter + Pagination works too,  but Filter + pagination + track by $index not working